# Perl Named Captured Group

Tags: regex, perl

I have created two named capture variables in the regex and the second one doesn't seem to return any value while the first one can. I am not sure why..here is the code.

```
my $string = 'test [google] another test [windows]';

my $regex=qr/\w*\[{1}(?<firstBracket>\w+)\]{1}(?<secondBracket>\w*)/ip;

$string=~ /$regex/;

say $+{secondBracket};
```

I am expecting that "secondBracket" will return.
I can do `$+{firstBracket}`, but not the second one...Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Spaces are not described in your pattern. `{1}` quantifiers are useless, remove them.

Comment: Don't use `m//` in void context. Always check whether the match succeeded before using any capture variables.

Answer (score 6):

You probably mean:

```
my $string = 'test [google] another test [windows]';

if( $string =~ /.*?\[(?<firstBracket>\w+)\].*?\[(?<secondBracket>\w+)\]/i ) {
        say $+{firstBracket};
        say $+{secondBracket};
}
```

output

```
google
windows
```

or

```
my $re = qr/.*?\[(?<firstBracket>\w+)\].*?\[(?<secondBracket>\w+)\]/i;
if( $string =~ $re ) {
    ...
}
```

with same output...

Comment: Thank you...I also realised that I didn't include the space between the first bracket and second bracket!! silly